# What is this victorian looking font with curls?

Tags: font-identification

Couldn't find this font using the usual tools...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Victorian Let Plain](https://www.wfonts.com/font/victorian-let) via wfonts.com

[image]

Comment: Also https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/victorian/std/